# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter. when using Selenium-Java 3.5.1 or above

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am wondering if anyone can give me an idea why I'm getting the following error when I use Selenium-Java 3.5.1 or above -

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.<init>(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)V from class org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker
```

Comment: Start with [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: Show your code, JDK version, full error message

Answer (score 7):

This error message...

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.<init>(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)V from class org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker
```

...implies that there was a mismatch between the version of the *WebDriver* variant (i.e. *GeckoDriver* / *ChromeDriver*) and the version of the respective *WebBrowser* variant (i.e. *Firefox* / *Chrome*) you are using.

> **Note**: You need to ensure that you are using the latest [JDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) versions.

---

### GeckoDriver-Selenium-Firefox

If you are using *GeckoDriver*-*Selenium*-*Firefox* combo, you need to follow the following compatibility chart:

[image: supported_platforms]

---

### ChromeDriver-Chrome

If you are using *ChromeDriver*-*Chrome* combo, you need to ensure that the binaries are compatible as per the entries below:

- ChromeDriver v101: Supports Chrome v101
- ChromeDriver v100: Supports Chrome v100
- ChromeDriver v99: Supports Chrome v99
- ChromeDriver v98: Supports Chrome v98
- ChromeDriver v97: Supports Chrome v97
- ChromeDriver v96: Supports Chrome v96
- ChromeDriver v95: Supports Chrome v95
- ChromeDriver v94: Supports Chrome v94
- ChromeDriver v93: Supports Chrome v93
- ChromeDriver v92: Supports Chrome v92
- ChromeDriver v91: Supports Chrome v91
- ChromeDriver v90: Supports Chrome v90
- ChromeDriver v89: Supports Chrome v89
- ChromeDriver v88: Supports Chrome v88
- ChromeDriver v87: Supports Chrome v87
- ChromeDriver v86: Supports Chrome v86
- ChromeDriver v85: Supports Chrome v85
- ChromeDriver v84: Supports Chrome v84
- ChromeDriver v83: Supports Chrome v83
- ChromeDriver v82: *Was intentionally skipped*
- ChromeDriver v81: Supports Chrome v81
- ChromeDriver v80: Supports Chrome v80
- ChromeDriver v79: Supports Chrome v79
- ChromeDriver v78: Supports Chrome v78
- ChromeDriver v77: Supports Chrome v77
- ChromeDriver v76: Supports Chrome v76
- ChromeDriver v75: Supports Chrome v75
- ChromeDriver v74: Supports Chrome v74
- ChromeDriver v73: Supports Chrome v73
- ChromeDriver v2.46: Supports Chrome v71-73
- ChromeDriver v2.45: Supports Chrome v70-72
- ChromeDriver v2.44: Supports Chrome v69-71 (same as ChromeDriver 2.43, but with additional bug fixes)
- ChromeDriver v2.43: Supports Chrome v69-71
- ChromeDriver v2.42: Supports Chrome v68-70
- ChromeDriver v2.41: Supports Chrome v67-69
- ChromeDriver v2.40: Supports Chrome v66-68
- ChromeDriver v2.39: Supports Chrome v66-68
- ChromeDriver v2.38: Supports Chrome v65-67
- ChromeDriver v2.37: Supports Chrome v64-66
- ChromeDriver v2.36: Supports Chrome v63-65
- ChromeDriver v2.35: Supports Chrome v62-64
- ChromeDriver v2.34: Supports Chrome v61-63
- ChromeDriver v2.33: Supports Chrome v60-62
- ChromeDriver v2.32: Supports Chrome v59-61
- ChromeDriver v2.31: Supports Chrome v58-60
- ChromeDriver v2.30: Supports Chrome v58-60
- ChromeDriver v2.29: Supports Chrome v56-58
- ChromeDriver v2.28: Supports Chrome v55-57
- ChromeDriver v2.27: Supports Chrome v54-56

> **Note**: A few months ago, *Chromium Team* made a [preliminary announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/HvlKWqv34es) that ChromeDriver's versioning model will be changing. Now *Chromium Team* is moving forward with the plan. Specifically, ChromeDriver 2.46 will be the last release carrying the major version of 2. Future ChromeDriver releases will carry a version number similar to Chrome release. We will start with a release of ChromeDriver 73 next week, before the Beta release of Chrome 73.

Here is how the new release model will work:

- ChromeDriver will be using the same version number scheme as Chrome. See https://www.chromium.org/developers/version-numbers for more details.
- Each version of ChromeDriver will support Chrome with matching major, minor, and build version numbers. For example, upcoming ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.* will support all Chrome versions that start with 73.0.3683.
- Before a new major version of Chrome goes to Beta, a matching version of ChromeDriver will be released. For example, a new version of ChromeDriver will be release next week to match the Beta release of Chrome m73.
- After the initial release of a new major version, we will release patches as needed. These patches may or may not coincide with updates to Chrome.

---

Further, this error `com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter` was also observed when a *Selenum Grid Node* appears to have successfully registered to the *Selenum Grid Hub* and was also confirmed from the grid console but when requesting for a session the following error was observed :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.create(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiter;
```

This error occured with `Selenium-Grid-Extras Hub (1.12.16)` due to *inconsistency between selenium and guava dependencies that are packaged into the JAR*

This issue was addressed through the merge [#367](https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras/pull/367) and using *Selenium v3.8.1* will solve your problem.

Ensure two points as :

- Selenium Grid Extras version is greater than (or equal to) 1.12.17
- guava dependencies are updated.

Comment: I still get the same error even after updating to Selenium v3.8.1, I'm actually also using testNG alongside selenium to run my tests. I'm running testNG v6.10 and selenium-java v3.8.1

Comment: Hmmm ... Your code trials, _pom.xml_ and the _error trace logs_ could have given us some hint whats wrong happening out there.

Comment: Same errror with driver matched browser version. Big trouble with portable browsers.

Answer (score 2):

In my earlier pom.xml, this was the entry:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Below error was being thrown,

> Error: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)V
>   from class org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker

Then I updated the POM with the latest version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I did not see the error once again. Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked for me. Needed to update selenium dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Check in you POM.XML file you will have 2 entry for "selenium-chrome-driver" dependency.
so, both dependency there and it is confuse which one need to take and giving you Exception. My one is working after this change.