# Selenium - IllegalAccessError

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I've added the dependency to my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And i'm trying to simplest test:

```
@Test
public void logInChromeTest() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

which gives me this :

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.<init>(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)V from class org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker
```

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

I have checked the solution given at [java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter. when using Selenium-Java 3.5.1 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48451021/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-tried-to-access-method-com-google-common-util-conc) and it did not fix my issue. Currently working with version 3.8.1 but still the same issue.

Comment: @DebanjanB I've edited my original post, the fix given in the previous answer did not resolve my issue.

Comment: Update your _guava dependency_. Better bump _Selenium Client_ to **v3.12.0**