# Selenium Java doesn't seem to work after following the official documentation

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I already read all answers/tutorials in google and Stack Overflow. I have followed the official documentation and tried different versions of chrome & chrome driver => https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
I already tried this => [java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter. when using Selenium-Java 3.5.1 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48451021/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-tried-to-access-method-com-google-common-util-conc)

But it doesn't work. I have try several chrome - chromeDriver versions, but always the same error.

- Google chrome version: 73.0.3683.56
- Chrome Driver version: 73.0.3683.20
- Selenium-java version: org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59
- sudo chmod +x chromedriver

Now I created a very simple tests:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/user/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.es/");
```

The browser doesn't open and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.<init>(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)V from class org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker

at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.<init>(UrlChecker.java:67)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:175)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:166)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:116)
at com.plfg.service.ChromeTest.testChromeEmail(ChromeTest.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Starting ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.7 (efcef9a3ecda02b2132af215116a03852d08b9cb) on port 19407
Only local connections are allowed.
```

pom.xml selenium dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Have you done a `webdriver-manager start` from the command line in the directory of your tests?

Comment: paste ur pom.xml for selenium standalone dependency and also for chromedirver.exe if u r not manually putting on build path?

Comment: No, I didn't did "webdriver-manager start". Do I have to? I thought the chromedriver is being started by new ChromeDriver() and I don't have to do it by console. I need to open the browser from my java applicacion because I need to retrieve informations from several websites. I don't want to depend on run anything from the comand line if it is possible.

Comment: I pasted my selenium dependency pom. I tried moving the seleniumdriver file to the same path where I'm using it. But still the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: I use a [Selenium Standalone Server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone) and I remember I switched to that when I couldn't get my tests working on Jenkins.  Have you tried that?  Otherwise you do need to add `webdriver-manager start` to start the selenium server.

Comment: Your code sample does not show ".exe" extension in the chromedriver.  Is that a typo?  It needs the full filename, looks like you're defining just a folder. `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/user/chromedriver");`

Comment: @Bill Hileman the chromedriver for linux doesn't have any extension

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to execute anything from the command line, I'd recommend running the selenium server using [Selenium Standalone Server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone).  I'm not too familiar with Travis so I hope/assume you can get it installed on there.