# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter with Selenium ChromeDriver Chrome with Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My Chrome version is 75.0.3770.142 and i'm using ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90 in my code with below pom dependency

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.3</version>
   </dependency>
```

When i try to run the test chromedriver doesn't get load.  it gives below error

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.<init>(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)V from class org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.<init>(UrlChecker.java:67) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.53.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:175) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.53.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:166) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.53.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.53.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.53.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.53.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.53.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.53.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-2.53.1.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:138) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-2.53.1.jar:na]
    at com.bfwg.service.impl.TestSuiteServiceImpl.loadWebDriver(TestSuiteServiceImpl.java:120) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.bfwg.service.impl.TestSuiteServiceImpl.execute(TestSuiteServiceImpl.java:86) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.bfwg.service.impl.TestSuiteServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$517eb5f7.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:669) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at 

Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90 (a6dcaf7e3ec6f70a194cc25e8149475c6590e025-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1003}) on port 23065
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
```

Comment: selenium 3.5.3 is too old

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.<init>(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)V from class org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *WebBrowser* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=75.0*
- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.5.3* of *2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z* which is almost **2** years older.
- Your *JDK version* is is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *Selenium Client v3.5.3* and *ChromeDriver v2.46*.

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  current levels [JDK 8u212](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v76.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=76.0.3809.68/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 76.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v76.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/76.0.3809.68/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test` as a **non root** user.

> You can find a detailed analysis on *com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter* in the discussion [java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter. when using Selenium-Java 3.5.1 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48451021/java-lang-illegalaccesserror-tried-to-access-method-com-google-common-util-conc/48462464#48462464)

Comment: I changed the selenium to 3.141 but still the same issue. my jdk version . but i can see some issue in maven tree it say selenium chrome driver as 2.53.

Comment: Finally i was able to solve this by upgrading springboot to 2.1.6.RELEASE. when i had 1.5 it downloads old chromedriver and continuously that gave above error.