# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter error using Maven

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, illegalaccessexception

When running my scripts, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.<init>(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)V from class org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker
```

Below is my pom.xml

```xml
  <properties>
    <entry_point>**/*Suite.java</entry_point>
    <serenity.version>1.1.39</serenity.version>
    <serenity.jbehave.version>1.9.0</serenity.jbehave.version>
    <webdriver.driver>chrome</webdriver.driver>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
      <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
      <artifactId>serenity-jbehave</artifactId>
      <version>${serenity.jbehave.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
      <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
      <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
      <artifactId>fest-util</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
      <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnError>false</failOnError>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>${entry_point}</include>
          </includes>
          <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
            <metafilter>-productionOnly</metafilter>
            <chrome.switches>--no-sandbox,--disable-extensions</chrome.switches>
            <webdriver.driver>${webdriver.driver}</webdriver.driver>
            <serenity.data.dir>..</serenity.data.dir>
            <serenity.step.delay>0</serenity.step.delay>
            <serenity.take.screenshots>FOR_FAILURES</serenity.take.screenshots>
            <serenity.driver.capabilities>
          unexpectedAlertBehaviour:ignore;ie.ensureCleanSession=true; 
            </serenity.driver.capabilities>
            <story.timeout.in.secs>1800</story.timeout.in.secs>
            <use.test.case.for.story.tag>false</use.test.case.for.story.tag>
            <untrusted.certificates>false</untrusted.certificates>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>serenity-reports</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>aggregate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I have tried updated the chromedriver and the serenity dependencies but that did not resolve the issue. Can anyone help me figure a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicated that there was a mismatch between the version of the WebDriver variant (i.e. GeckoDriver / ChromeDriver) and the version of the respective WebBrowser variant (i.e. Firefox / Chrome) you are using.

Make Sure you are using latest JDK version, if not then update your JDK and try again. That may help.
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: My chromedriver version is 100.0.4896.60 and the browser version is 100.0.4896.75 and JDK version is 1.8.0_251. I know it's not the latest but there other testers on my project with the same JDK version and they are not having any issues at all.

Comment: But your pom.xml tells the compiler to use language level 7 - could that be a problem? (source and target both set to `1.7`)

Comment: @cyberbrain so I changed it to 1.8 to see if that would fix it and it threw a compilation error

Comment: _compilation_ error? Thats super strange - I could imagine a runtime error but not compilation. Can you give more details about it?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.<init>(Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)V from class org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker
```

...implies that there are some **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using.

---

### Solution

Ensure that *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u311](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html).
Incase you are using *ChromeDriver* / *Chrome* combo, ensure that:

- *Chrome* is upgraded to ***Chrome Version 100.0.4896.88***
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to [ChromeDriver v100.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=100.0.4896.60/) level.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter. when using Selenium-Java 3.5.1 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48462464/7429447)